# Unable to send api key (authorisation token) in GET (JQUERY AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax, get, token, access-token

Using AJAX I am trying to initiate a GET request to a rest API. I am passing access token in the header. The whole setup is working very fine in the localhost (Xampp).

PHP code used in API is working fine as I have checked it with postman.

Then I tried it on a web host (000webhost.com) and I am getting 400 error. On further investigation I found that the api is returning "API Key is missing"

> GET https://alientechno.000webhostapp.com/step_muzic/v1/get_owner_main_page?_=1519553873190 400 ()

```
<script>
var status = checkLoginStatus();

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (2*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
          c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
          return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
  return "";
  }

  $(document).ready(function() { 

    //var api = getCookie("api_key");
    //alert(api);
    //if(status==true)
    var api = getCookie("api_key");
     $.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     url :'https://alientechno.000webhostapp.com/v1/get_owner_main_page',
     result: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     headers: {"Authorization": api},
     success: function(result) {
        var output="";
        var output_school="";
         for (var i in result.MF)
         {
            output+="<tr><td>" + result.MF[i].id + "</td><td>" + result.MF[i].name + "</td><td>" + result.MF[i].net_royalty +"</td><td>"+ result.MF[i].royalty_to_owner +"</td></tr>";
         }

       output+="<tr><td style='background-color:#aabb05;text-color:white;box-shadow:2px 2px;'>TOTAL</td><td></td><td style='background-color:#aabb05;color:white;'>"+result.total_mf_royalty+"</td><td style='background-color:#aabb05;color:white;'>"+result.total_mf_royalty_to_owner+"</td></tr>";

         for(var i in result.Schools){
            output_school += "<tr><td>" + result.Schools[i].id + "</td><td>" + result.Schools[i].name + "</td><td>" + result.Schools[i].credit+"</td><td>"+ result.Schools[i].debit+"</td><td>"+result.Schools[i].net_income+"</td><td>"+result.Schools[i].royalty_to_owner+"</td><td>"+result.Schools[i].royalty_other+"</td></tr>";
         }

       output_school+="<tr><td style='background-color:#aabb05;text-color:white;box-shadow:2px 2px;'>TOTAL</td><td></td><td style='background-color:#aabb05;color:white;'>"+result.total_school_credit+"</td><td style=''></td><td style=''></td><td style='background-color:#aabb05;color:white;'>"+result.total_school_royalty_to_owner+"</td><td style='background-color:#aabb05;color:white;'>"+result.total_school_royalty_other+"</td></tr>";

         $('#mfTable').append(output);
         $('#schoolTable').append(output_school);
     },

     error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
     //var tokenString = ;


  }); 

  });
```

Comment: Can you post your `getCookie` code? And the content of `api`

Comment: What does `console.log(api)` show?

Comment: @CapitanFindus the api is working fine in POSTMAN so I think its not an API issue...

Comment: @shrish123kumar on Postman you are setting the correct header, so probably it's what's missing on your javascript code. So I asked for its content. `api = getCookie("api_key");` it's what you wrote

Comment: @Barman 400 bad request...its due to api_key missing i had this logic in the api to send 400 bad error

Comment: also this is working fine when I try this in my Office and obviously at localhost...but at other location its not working...may be its a brower issue ,I have to enable or disable something.

Comment: using console.. if find that it is sending api_key in the request header

Comment: @CapitanFindus if you are not convinced I can post my getCookie code

Comment: @shrish123kumar Could be useful, It's what I was asking at first

Comment: @CapitanFindus cookie is not an issue because even when I send some random string in the header the API is still returning "api key missing" instead of "incorrect api key"